# FOR XML PATH produces only first item

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two tables: Reservations and ReservationNights (every reservation has many nights).

[image]

In a stored procedure, I have a variable that looks like this: `@roomTypeList = '2;3;4;5;'` -> its a list of RoomUseIds.

I need to display only the reservations that have a reservation nights with one of those Ids (In this example, it should display only reservation 14105, because there are existing nights where RoomUseId = 3 and the `'2;3;4;5;'` variable contains 3.

I've tried to use something like this, but it doesn't produce good results - sometimes it displays only 1 reservations when multiple should be displayed, usually it displays nothing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.Id, r.BookingStatus, r.CurrencyId
        FROM Reservations r
        --JOIN ReservationNights rn ON rn.ReservationId = r.Id
        WHERE
(@roomTypeListLocal IS NULL OR (@roomTypeListLocal LIKE ('%' + CAST((SELECT STUFF((SELECT ';' + CAST(rn.RoomUseId as nvarchar(MAX))
                FROM ReservationNights rn
                WHERE rn.ReservationId = r.Id AND rn.RoomUseId IS NOT NULL
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')) as nvarchar(MAX)) + ';%')))
```

Comment: Please, copy the sample data to text instead of images, so we can copy and paste it. And you should also provide expected results, so we can help you with your query.

Comment: Having a `FOR XML PATh` in the `WHERE` feels like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). Why do you need to compare to a delimited string in the `WHERE` in the first place?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You key issue is lack of normalization. If you have a list, store it as a list.**

So you need a table variable or Table Valued parameter. *At a pinch,* you can split your existing string, but it's better to have the data in the right format in the first place.

```sql
DECLARE @roomTypeList TABLE (roomType int PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @roomTypeList (roomType)
SELECT *
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@roomTypeListLocal, ';');

SELECT
  r.Id,
  r.BookingStatus,
  r.CurrencyId
FROM Reservations r
WHERE
    @roomTypeListLocal IS NULL
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM ReservationNights rn
        JOIN @roomTypeList rl ON rl.roomType = rn.RoomUseId
        WHERE rn.ReservationId = r.Id
    );
```

---

If you *really* wanted to stick with a comma-separated list, you could merge `STRING_SPLIT` into the above query, rather than trying to construct an equivalent aggregated string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest an alternative approach: make sure your variable has a delimiter before and after every value (eg: `';2;3;4;5;'`), and use an `EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.Id, r.BookingStatus, r.CurrencyId
FROM Reservations r
WHERE
(
    @roomTypeListLocal IS NULL
OR
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM ReservationNights rn
        WHERE rn.ReservationId = r.Id
        AND rn.RoomUseId IS NOT NULL
        AND @roomTypeListLocal LIKE ';' + CAST(rn.RoomUseId As varchar(10)) + ';'
    )
)
```